# Simple Conduction Simulation

Tags: thermodynamics, simulations

What is the simplest way to simulate heat conduction on a 2D plane?

What I want to do is have 1024x1024 2D plane of uniform temperature 0°C and specify the temperature of a cartesian coordinate. Then, over time I want to simulate the temperature of each coordinate on the plane.

So far all I found are simulations for 3d systems and programs such as FloTherm.

Comment: Are you looking for a software that will do it for you or do you want to implement the simulation yourself in some more general numerical software? Maybe you can specify what you mean by "simple".

Comment: There is absolutely nothing simple about solving partial differential equations on meshes, neither with home grown nor with commercial code. Particularly the naive discretization of an equation will usually not produce reliable results. Heat flow is a little more forgiving than wave equations, if I remember correctly, but it will pay to consult a number of textbooks on numerical solutions of partial differential equations. The subject is far too complex to try to re-invent the wheel. Even if you just want to "drive" a commercial software engine, you should get a "driver's license", first.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm rather surprised about your comment. Numerical solution to the heat equation (assuming no convection) is probably one of the simplest problems in computational physics and to my understanding a part of any standard undergrad curriculum. What makes the problem even simpler is that here we are dealing with a 2D plane, with the 1024x1024 grid implying that there is little more geometrical structure. Spectral methods, FEM and FDM should all prove very straightforward. As for the question, the simplest way is probably to take someone else's code: Google e.g. "python pde solver".

Comment: @alarge: "one of the simplest" unfortunately does not mean "simple". I would suggest to take a glance at the literature to understand the detailed problems. I did, by the way, have similar ideas about numerical mathematics... until my first class on the subject, which cured me of that naive approach. So, in a way, I understand why you would think this way.

Comment: @CuriousOne I do not wish to start a chat about how much either of us has studied numerical mathematics. Fact is that the concepts required to solve the heat equation (the one presented in the question) are very simple (and by this I mean that it is a part of standard physics curricula). We can always make matters more rigorous using Sobolev spaces etc., but claiming that this is necessary to solve the simple problem presented in the question is analogous to suggesting that understanding differential forms and manifolds is necessary to do anything in F=ma classical mechanics: Simply not true.

Comment: @alarge: I am glad to have met such a specialist on the matter and I will leave it to yourself to reinsure yourself about your complete understanding of the matter. You are right, we have nothing to discuss. It would be an utter waste of my time.

Comment: generally, a 3-D solver can handle a 2-d problem. Just make a slab and insulate the two faces in the direction that you don't need (let's call it Z).  As long as you eliminate all gradients in Z it really won't matter.  If you do want to code yourself, an explicit finite-difference  method is pretty easy to make for a uniform grid and a good introduction to PDEs in general. There are many examples of this online.